# What is a good software package for ( assisted ) theorem proving and documenting?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, computer-algebra-systems

Background: An issue in my math study is that I haven't found a good way of storing the theorems ( mostly abstract algebra ) I studied and want to (re-)use in proofs. At the moment I use a personal Wiki and LaTeX but that doesn't -do- much for me. So I am thinking of investing time in learning an automated theorem prover package to which I am fairly newbie at the moment. A first Google search lead me to **ACL2, Isabelle and Prover9** and that's where the confusion starts.

**Question:
- Given my requirements of documenting and re-using theorems which software tool is a good option to use? ( I have done a mathematical logic course already. )**

Comment: [Aotomated Theorem Proving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving#Comparison)

Comment: Thanks @pedja but from my perspective this only adds to the confusion. I don't want to follow dead tracks.

Comment: @ndroock1: Automated theorem proving is about proving theorems in the sense of mathematical logic. Given that the vast majority of mathematicians do not write their proofs in formal systems, I think it is highly unlikely that an automatic theorem prover will be able to help you learn mathematics.

Comment: @ZhenLin - My issue is not learning the theorems, but documenting them in a -productive- way. I read from the Isabelle project that it may become a requirement in the near future that when a paper is submitted to a journal the proofs should be readable by a formal system.

Comment: @ndroock1: I think "near future" is very optimistic. Look at any paper submitted to a mathematical journal, or any mathematics textbook. In my view, your wish to "document" theorems is just a means to the goal of learning them – you have not really understood a theorem until you know how to use it!